# Merge conflict when merging from release branch to master after using Cherry pick?

Tags: git, merge

We use Git Flow and have a release branch, we constantly Cherry pick from branch commits that fixes bugs that we need in our develop branch aswell. Sometimes we get conflicts when doing a cherrypick. When the release is out we would obviously merge the release branch into our develop. Would we get the same conflicts again that we once solved in the cherrypick ?

Also maybe there are other better ways to sync our develop with the bugfixes from the release branch ?

donnib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [git flow model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), you should apply bug fixes that are in your release branch to the develop branch not by cherry picking, but by merging. You mention that you do this merge when "the release is out," but there is no reason to wait for that; just merge from release into develop whenever you fix a bug in release.

(**Edit**: responding to question in comment)

You mentioned that there are certain changes (like version numbers and whatnot) in the release branch you do not want in develop. If you know what all these changes are when you first branch release off of develop, make those changes to release right after you branch off of develop, then merge release back into develop with `git merge release -s ours`. This will cause a merge commit to happen, but no files in develop will actually change. Then, future merges into develop will not bring in those unwanted changes, because as far as git is concerned they have already been merged in. Now after your release, if you *do* want those changes merged into develop, you will indeed have to cherry-pick that one single commit onto develop, but that is probably preferable to having to do multiple cherry-picks as you are doing now.

Comment: Yes that's true but usually there are commits in the Release branch which you don't want into Develop such as commits that change versions and prepares for release. How do you handle that ?

Comment: Actually there is a line stating something about this like : "This step may well lead to a merge conflict (probably even, since we have changed the version number). If so, fix it and commit." but we would only get conflict if changes also were made in develop otherwise Git would just commit the change.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i needed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your process but it doesn't sound right. Git Flow is about a 3 tier process. The three tiers are your release branches (rel#.#), your intermediate development branches (dev) and your defect fix or feature enhancement branches (task#).

My GitFlow dev cycle:

1. pull from last approved rel#.# branch to new dev branch. From this
   point on the rel#.# branch is static.
2. pull from dev to task#
   Work, test, re-sync against dev (resolve merge conflicts), push
   completed task work to dev. To ensure my pushes to dev are
   fast-forwards, i.e. no merge bubbles, re-sync using
   "git pull --rebase origin dev" daily and when task is completed and ready to push
3. push (to dev) and collect (in dev) all tasks slated for new release and
   stop task pushes to dev, i.e. freeze remote dev for new tasks
4. test dev and push fixes to dev for new release
5. push final dev to new release branch with new versioned branch name
6. delete dev, back to step #1

git cherry-pick can only pick off and merge commits which can have changes to files that you don't want. Use file targeted git checkout to get only the file changes within a commit you want.

To get a very isolated change from a single file for the same file in a different branch, use good old fashion cut and paste.

Answer (score 0):

Why are there bugfix commits in your feature branch?

Bugfixes should be on a separate branch from feature branch (or push to release branch directly), and every bug fix and new feature can have a separate branch so that you never had to cherry-pick individual commits.

Comment: That was a typo, i have fixed the question.

Comment: The bugfixes are indeed made in their own branch based on the release branch so a merge would not work because it would take more stuff into develop than just that branch.

Comment: @dbrasco - you should never have something in the release branch that should not be merged into develop, because release branches from develop, and contains only bug fixes that should also be in develop. What is the "more stuff" that you don't want merged into develop?

Comment: @DavidDeutsch see my comment above.